# how to compile a C program in DLX linux in Bochs

Tags: c, gcc, x86, simulator, bochs

I have installed Bochs and DLX linux in it. I wrote a Hello world C program in it. But I don't know how to compile the program in it.

When i type gcc hello.c i get an error saying "bash: gcc: command not found".

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you don't have `gcc` installed.

Comment: @ Daniel , yes i see that but how do i install gcc in DLX linux in Bochs ?

Answer (score 0):

DLXLINUX is a very small and a bit outdated distro. Maybe you need to create a certain environment inside the image in order to use gcc and stuff.

Here is a small tutorial teaching how to set a network for it. Maybe after it you can play with it:

http://bochs.sourceforge.net/doc/docbook/user/dlxlinux-networking.html